# WebApi site with Windows Authentication and workgroups?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi2 site running in IIS 8.5 with Windows Authentification enabled. the site is working fine.

However, I would like to set up the site within a Workgroups environment instead of Active Directoy.

What are the changes necessary in IIS and/or `web.config` so that Windows Authentification can still be used?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566204/setup-windows-authentication-for-asp-net-using-local-workgroups

Comment: I cannot try it in my machine but this answer should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566204/setup-windows-authentication-for-asp-net-using-local-workgroups